# Parsing json response from youtube api

Tags: python, json, api, youtube

I want to save a json response to an object and parse the content. I call a youtube api request with the code

```
response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,snippet,statistics,topicDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IT&maxResults=25&key=MYAPIKEY")
```

then i have a 200 code and a successfull api response.

Next i save the json output to a new object called data

```
data = response.json()
```

now i'm trying to obtain for every video returned its information for a subsequent sql storage. I'm trying with this code

```
for item in data['items']:
    print('description')
```

I receive the error key error: description. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in data['items']:
    print('description')
```

isn't what you want. `print ('description')` is an instruction to print the literal string `description`. Did you perhaps mean `print(item['description'])`? This would let you access the `item` as a dictionary.

Or possibly you copied your code incorrectly. A `KeyError` occurs when you try to access a dictionary key that doesn't exist. For example:

```
>>> d = {'baz': 'foo'}
>>> d['quux']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'quux'
```

I would explore your data and make sure that the keys you're trying to access are actually present. If you update your question with more information about the API documentation, I could help more.